# circle intersection with rectangle - binary image processing with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I need help detecting the areas in which the rectangles and the circles intersect using morphological algorithms applicable with MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox. A hint or an idea to the solution would be sufficient, no need for a MATLAB script.

Example picture:

[image: img]

Solution to the example:

[image: img]

Comment: Unfortunately stackoverflow is not a *hitning* webpage. Show us what you tried

Comment: Remove the circles that don't intersect with the rectangles with an appropriate structuring element, then take a look at the **hit-or-miss** transform: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwhitmiss.html